# object.notify() doesn't wake up object.wait()

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to user '`synchronized(object) {object.wait()}`' to pause my server till object is ready. And I have called '`synchronized(object) {object.notify() }`' in the class which will set the object value. But it seems like my server never wake up after `wait()`.

```
public class MyServer {
...
do {
            try {

                message = (String) in.readObject();
                System.out.println("server receive>" + message);

                synchronized (myServerSend) {
                    myServerSend.wait();
                }

                System.out.println("Am I wake up???"); //this never print out

                sendMessage(myServerSend);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnot) {
                System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
            }
        } while (!message.equals("bye"));

    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
....
}
```

Here is my calls for setting object value

```
public class Action implements MouseInputListener, MouseMotionListener {

    ....

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {...
    }

        else {
            ....
            if(MyGame.currentPlayer == MyGame.WHITE) {
                    myServerSend = "" + chosenPieceIndex + "," + moveLocationIndex;
                    synchronized (myServerSend) {

                        myServerSend.notify(); // this seems like fail to wake up myServer

                    }
                    System.out.println(myServerSend);
}
```

Will it be a problem if I declare myServerSend as a public static string type?
Could anyone help with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this same object `myServerSend` in both classes? Is it possible that client executed `notify()` before server actually reaches `wait()`?

Comment: Where is the `myServerSend` variable declared?

Comment: I am sure myServerSend is the same object in both classes. In this case, Action class will be called on server side.

Comment: I forget to show the declaration of myServerSend here, but I am pretty sure I did that

Comment: the object referenced by myServerSend is replaced when you assign a new value to it (since strings are immutable), there is no way both pieces of code are using the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you got to the notify code before the wait. You should always put thread.wait() inside while loop for that reason (and also due to spurious wake up - but for this reason do while is good enough).

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure exactly what is wrong with your code as written, the code is inherently unsafe.  If nothing else, there is no guarantee that the call to `wait()` happens before `notify()` -- if notify happens first, the wait will last forever.  Additionally, [wait may wake up spuriously](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29), so even if you fix that you will still not have correct code:

> A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or
>   timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur
>   in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the
>   condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and
>   continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied. In other words,
>   waits should always occur in loops, like this one:
>
> ```
>  synchronized (obj) {
>      while (<condition does not hold>)
>          obj.wait(timeout);
>      ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
>  }
> ```

You might consider replacing this code with a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html), or maybe even a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).  These classes are all much easier and less error prone to use.  `wait`/`notify` are lower level and somewhat harder to use correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little hard to give a definitive answer without seeing all of the code, but the problem may lie here:

```
myServerSend = "" + chosenPieceIndex + "," + moveLocationIndex;
synchronized (myServerSend) {
    myServerSend.notify(); // this seems like fail to wake up myServer
}
```

Are you sure that this object (myServerSend) is indeed the same as the MyServer.myServerSend object? It looks like myServerSend is created in the Action class and from what you describe the expected order is MyServer and then Action, but as I say myServerSend seems to be created in MyServer.

In other words if the order of evens should be MyServer and then Action I would have expected the locking object to be created either outside of both, or in the MyServer class.

So at a guess I would say that you're not synchronzing on the same object and if this is true it would explain the behaviour you're seeing.

If however you are sure that this is the same object then the order of events **must** be Action and then MyServer (or you'd get a NullPointerException in MyServer), and if thats the case I'd guess that you're notifying before you wait, and so your code stays at the wait point forever, waiting for a notification that its already missed.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks! I see the problem. Should I change the wait() function in myServer as 'synchronized(Action.myServerSend) {Action.myServerSend.notify(); }'?

Comment: myServerSend is a public static string which is declared in Action class

Comment: Yes, provided its the same object that you're locking/waiting/notifying on you should be fine.  An alternative could be (but this may complicate it for you) that MyServer waits on itself (using the "this" keyword) and Action locks on the instance of MyServer. This could perhaps be a later improvement once you have your first iteration working. Note however that once you have this working and are happy with it, you may want to investigate the alternative mechanisms in java.util.concurrent (since Java 5) - they're much easier to work with than the low level mechanisms at play here.